# Homotopy equivalence of Topologist's sine curve

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

I'm currently studying algebraic topology and I have the following question.

There are two similar topological spaces as below.

Below is a union of two Topologist's sine curves, and a square is added in the above.

[image]

I guess they are not homotopy equivalent, but I cannot find the reasoning.

Can anybody give some explanation? Thank you in advance.

(Added)
Let $T = \{(x,sin(\frac{1}{x})):x \in (0,1)\} \cup \{0\} \times [-1,1]$ be the Topologist's sine curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$.
Similarly, $T' = \{(x,sin(\frac{-1}{x})):x \in (-1,0)\} \cup \{0\} \times [-1,1]$

Below : $T \cup T'$
Above : $\{0\} \times [-1,1]$ is replaced by $[-1,1] \times [-1,1]$, and sine curve is translated accordingly.

Comment: Why do you think they are not homotopy equivalent? Also, it would be nice if you could write down your description of the spaces in unambiguous notation (e.g. what does "with a square added" mean?), rather than a picture. It it possible someone might give an answer based on a reading of your picture that is not what you intended.

Comment: @William Thank you for the suggestion! I will write down the description of the spaces as well :)

Comment: My bad! @PaulFrost => +1 and +1

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are not homotopy equivalent.

Let
$$L = \{0\} \times [-1,1], \\ R = [-1,1]^2 , \\  S_\pm = \{(\pm x,\sin \frac 1 x) \mid x \in (0,1) \}, \\ S'_\pm = \{(\pm (x +1),\sin \frac 1 x) \mid x \in (0,1) \}.$$
We have to compare
$$T = S_+ \cup S_- \cup L$$
and
$$T' = S'_+ \cup S'_- \cup R .$$

Both spaces have three path components. Let $f : T \to T'$ be any map. It maps each of the path components $S_+, S_-,L$ of $T$ into one of the path components  $S'_+,S'_-,R$ of $T'$.

Let $f^* : P \to P'$ the associated map between the set of path components. In order that $f$ be a homotopy equivalence, a necessary condition is that $f^*$ is a bijection. We shall show the assumption that $f^*$ is a bijection leads to a contradiction.

Case 1. $f(L) \subset S'_+$.

Since $f^*$ is bijective, we must have $f(S_+ \cup S_-) \subset S'_- \cup R$. The closure of $S_+ \cup S_-$ contains $L$, thus  $f(L)$ must be contained in the closure of $f(S_+ \cup S_-)$ and thus contained in $S'_- \cup R$. This contradicts the assumption in case 1.

Case 2. $f(L) \subset S'_-$.

This is treated similarly.

Case 3. $f(L) \subset R$.

Then $f(S_+)$ must be contained in one of $S'_\pm$. W.l.o.g. we may assume $f(S_+) \subset S'_+$. It follows that $f(S_-) \subset S'_-$.

Since $L$ is contained in the closure of both $S_\pm$, we see that $f(L)$ must be contained in the closure of both $f(S_\pm)$ and thus in the closure of both $S'_\pm$. But these closures are disjoint, a contradiction.

Comment: Wow, this is a beautiful argument using the basic property of continuity. Thanks Paul!